# Использование в аббревиатуре союза "и"

Tags: аббревиатура

Нужно ли в аббревиатуре названия должности использовать союз "и"? Должность называется *инженер по комплектации и сопровождению инвестиционных проектов,* соответственно варианты написания аббревиатуры следующие: *инженер по КСИП* и *инженер по КиСИП* — какой из них наиболее верный?

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения благозвучности звучания и простоты написания я бы выбрал вариант *без И.* Не думаю, что есть рекомендации по тому, когда можно опускать этот союз. Нашёл лишь указание на то, что он передаётся строчной буквой (§208 у [Лопатина](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80_%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)), но видно, что вы и так это прекрасно понимаете.

Вообще, союз И в аббревиатурах иногда опускается, как в названии факультета МГУ — ***ВМК*** (вычислительной математики **и** кибернетики), а иногда его оставляют — ***МИСиС*** (Московский институт стали и сплавов). Предположу, что в последнем случае это сделано для лучшего звучания и чтобы не путать со словом *мисс.*

Comment: Бывает даже, что пишется но не читается, например, ЦПКиО в Ленинграде (Центральный парк культуры и отдыха), произносится "цэ-пэ-кэ-о".

Comment: Да, интересно, спасибо за пример!